# What is causing this djcelery error: NotRegistered?

Tags: python, django, django-celery

Running this script in a django shell:

```
import processors.topics.tasks as t
t.test.delay()
```

Gives this error:

```
NotRegistered: 'processors.topics.tasks.test'
```

The weird thing is that chorus.processors.topics.tasks.test is *definitely* included in the [Tasks] printout when I run

```
python celeryd --verbosity=2 --loglevel=INFO --purge
```

Why am I getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the way you are importing the task for example, You are importing the task from the project instead of the app, `chorus.processors.topics` tasks instead of `processors.topics.tasks`. This creates problems for Celery, since the name will be different in the client and the server.

Here are the docs that relate to the following [issue](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-naming-and-relative-imports)

Comment: You don't have to register tasks anymore, but the link you provided is indeed relevant.  You are importing the task from the project instead of the app, `chorus.processors.topics.tasks` instead of `processors.topics.tasks`.  This creates problems for Celery, since the name will be different in the client and the server: http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-naming-and-relative-imports